# install sfSwiftPlugin for Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, swiftmailer

I am using Symfony 1.4 as PHP framework, with Propel as ORM. I downloaded sfSwiftPlugin 1.5.1, but it was for 1.o version, and when installing it is giving me error `you try to install a symfony 1.0 plugin`. how can in upgrade the Plugin, or is there any other plugin for mailing purpose. 
Can we use the core PHP Mail function, in Symfony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to install the swift plugin. Swift is the default mailer in sf 1.3/1.4. Please see the documentation [Docu](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/11-Emails)

Comment: i.e i will have to directly call the methods of swift mailer to do the corresponding process...